# How do I fight Mongols with big axes?

Tags: ghost-of-tsushima

One of the enemy types I've encountered are Mongol soldiers with a big axe. At first they looked like the fight should be very similar to fights against soldiers with spears. But after a few times, I think I'm missing something with these enemies. I can' reliably dodge their red flashing attacks, and I've been hit often enough now that I don't think this is me messing up the timing. They have some big, sweeping attacks that I can't seem to dodge, but as they're flashing red they are obviously also unblockable.

These attacks are very annoying as they take a serious amount of health and knock me down. How can I avoid these kinds of attacks from the axe-wielding Mongols? Are there any specific tricks to this type of enemy?

Comment: According to ingame tips you can avoid sweeping attacks by jumping, I never tried it though as dodging seems to give enough iframes to go through anything. I guess either your dodge timing is a bit off when they swipe or I got lucky/confused enough and never noticed I did not actually dodge them.

Comment: Perhaps buying the dodge roll (double tap circle) would give you the dodge distance needed? I have not yet encountered this enemy type

Answer (score 4):

Getting (and using) the Moon Stance would be the best method for killing these enemies. After they've attacked, or before they get the chance to attack, press Triangle repeatedly until their guard is broken, then continue to attack with either Triangle or Square.

It will also be useful to learn their moves and how they are signaled. For example, if he raises the axe above his head, he will swing down the axe in front of him. You would want to dodge with Circle. Often times, they will go from one move right into another. The best way to observe these moves is keeping a few meters of distance from them, and either jumping or dodging as they are doing their attacks (even if they are very far away).

Alternatively, you can use throwing weapons such as the kunai or sticky bombs to stagger/damage them, then attack them while they are vulnerable. It may also help to shoot them once or twice with an arrow from a farther distance.

Answer (score 2):

The big Mongols are called "Brutes".

In the Samurai techniques section you can learn Evasion - the very first one gives you a roll which should move you out of reach.

The Moon Stance is specifically for Brutes but it is the last of the four that you get so it takes a fair bit of effort to acquire.

The heavy arrows of the Longbow can also do a lot of ranged damage. And there are also the various quick fire weapons.

The Samurai Clan armour reduces the damage you receive quite a lot.

Comment: I think the ones I mean are slightly different from the Brutes you describe. The brutes with the big cudgel I can handle, but the ones with an axe seem to have different moves.

Comment: I think all the big guys are classed as Brutes